# How to use rule in gitlab-ci to run after specific manual job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following stages:

```
  - run
  - notify
```

when run have 3 jobs: `run-prod, run-stg, run-dev`

which all of them are triggered only by manual action because they require env variables.

The problem is that i want to run `notify` step only if `run` actually runs (on not manual pipelines its not run) - how can i do it?

i tried with `needs` and `only` but its not working

notify jobs:

```
notify on run success:
  stage: notify
  extends: .dv.notify.slack_channel
  variables:
    SLACK_MESSAGE: "\" Recovery process which triggered by $GITLAB_USER_NAME finished successfully on context: $CONNECT_CONTEXT, connector: $CONNECT_NAME, connectors: $CONNECTORS_NAMES\""
    SLACK_CHANNEL: C02AX03H04F #recovery



notify on run failure:
  stage: notify
  extends: .dv.notify.slack_channel
  variables:
    SLACK_MESSAGE: "\"️ Recovery process which triggered by $GITLAB_USER_NAME failed on context: $CONNECT_CONTEXT, connector: $CONNECT_NAME, connectors: $CONNECTORS_NAMES\""
    SLACK_CHANNEL: C02AX03H04F #recovery
```

run-stg:

```
run-stg:
  extends: run
  script: ...
  rules:
    - if: $CONNECT_CONTEXT =~ /^cs-*/
      when: manual
```

Comment: Aren't you able to use the same conditions that you have applied to your `run` jobs?

Comment: not, because they not passed to the next stage

Comment: If you define your variables in a global `variables` section those should be available in all stages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimal example config that requires manual input of the `CONNECT_CONTEXT` variable:

```yaml
stages:
  - run
  - notify

variables:
  CONNECT_CONTEXT:
    description: Your description for this variable.

run:
  stage: run
  rules:
    - if: $CONNECT_CONTEXT =~ /^cs-*/
  script:
    - echo run $CONNECT_CONTEXT

notify:
  stage: notify
  rules:
    - if: $CONNECT_CONTEXT =~ /^cs-*/
  script:
    - echo notify $CONNECT_CONTEXT
```

[image: GitLab UI]

Comment: And CONNECT_CONTEXT is supplied via the manual pipeline? btw - is there a way to store the keys on the repo for next use? instead of writing them all over again?

Comment: Yes, `CONNECT_CONTEXT` can be set conveniently via GitLab's UI. I don't understand your question about keys, maybe you'd want to ask a separate question?

Comment: Yes, but now every pipeline that i'm running i need to set the CONNECT_CONTEXT, i want to pre-defined that the user don't need to think which key he needs (need to go to readme or something)

Comment: You can [prefill variables in manual pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/index.html#prefill-variables-in-manual-pipelines) – not sure if that's what you're asking for…